# Not getting option of run on "Device" for a cordova windows phone app in visual studio 2013

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-cordova

I have developed a windows app with cordova.
I can run that App on "local machine" and "Simulator" in visual studio.
but to build that app in my windows phone, I am not getting option of "Device" to run in my phone.
I'm using this command "cordova run windows --device -- --phone" on command prompt to run that App in my phone. that is working fine.
But I need to build the App in my mobile through Visual studio2013.
tell me how to get get the option of "Device" to run.

Comment: Is it possible for you to upgrade/install to Visual Studio Community 2015?  If so, do it now!

Answer (score 1):

You need the Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova.

then follow:

> 1. With your app open in Visual Studio, choose Windows Phone 8 or
>      Windows Phone (Universal) from the Solution Platforms list. If you
>      don’t see this option, choose Solution Platforms from the Add/Remove
>      Buttons list to display it.
> 2. Choose Device.
> 3. Press F5 to start the app
>
>    Visual Studio starts the app on the connected Windows Phone device.

You can find link for VS studio Tools for Apache Cordova in the link below -

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn757055(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: I have already chosen "Windows Phone 8" but it is not displaying "Device" anywhere :(